# Когда сервер узнает что я закончил передачу? (WinSock)

Tags: сокет

Опять в голове получилась "непонятка". Например есть HTTP сервер. Шлю я ему запрос с помощью сокетов.
Например я сделал send(sock, buff, buff_size, 0), а вдруг сервер пришли данные меньше, чем buffsize? Что тогда? Сервер ожидает отправки остальной части? Как ее правильно отправить? 
И другой вопрос, как тогда отправить строку по частям с буффером?
Если я вышлю кусок HTTP запроса, сервер ведь его обработает и выдаст что-то вроде "страница не найдена" или вообще HTTP ERROR.

Comment: Или для этого и сущесвует TCP/IP и Content-Length в этом случае?. Первый обеспечит надежность доставки. А второе позволит передавать страницу кусками. Так что ли?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы путаете TCP и HTTP. Если вы по TCP послали кусок данных, то он так и будет принят на том конце. Когда вы пошлёте продолжение, то продолжение будет так же обработано сервеом. Если смотреть на эту ситуацию с точки зрения HTTP, то HTTP серверу наплевать, каким порциями будут приходить данные. Хоть по одному байту посылайте.

История с Content-Length - это совсем другая тема и предназначена как раз для того, чтобы сервер знал, сколько всего данных надо принять (не важно какими частями). А до этого он просто читает по строкам (заголовки запроса) до тех пор, пока не встретит два перевода строки подряд. И да, он будет ждать столько, сколько нужно.

> Если я вышлю кусок HTTP запроса, сервер ведь его обработает и выдаст что-то вроде "страница не найдена" или вообще HTTP ERROR.

Учитывая, что он читает по строкам, то ничего такого не произойдёт.

**UPD** Ах да, про отправку. Это будет что-то в таком духе (если char * buff)

```
int sent = 0;
while (sent < buff_size) {
    int rc = send(sock, buff + sent, buff_size - sent, 0);
    if (rc > 0) {
        sent += rc;
    } else if (rc == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: Тут даже смешнее. Передавамые куски TCP сцепляет. Это - труба. То, что до вас ещё не дошло, не означает, что не было послано.

Comment: Я отправляю данные... Кусками. Когда сервер узнает, что нужно их уже обрабатывать? HTTP выходит считывает данные, когда получает \\r\\n то обрабатывает, а когда два подряд обрабатывает весь запрос?

Comment: Кажется понял. TCP просто обеспечивает доставку данных такими, какими я их отправил. А уже в зависимости от протокола существуют свои способы "понимания" будет ли клиент что-то слать еще или стоит уже отправить ему ответ. Так?

Comment: Совершенно верно.

Comment: Наконец-то прояснилось. Спасибо всем!

Answer (score 1):

C TCP всё просто (из man 3 recv):

Upon successful completion, recv() shall return the length of the message in bytes. If no messages are available to be received and the peer has performed an orderly shutdown, recv() shall return 0. Otherwise, -1 shall be returned and errno set to indicate the error.

Т.е. длина == 0 - закрытие сокета. Ну а то, что Вы не имеете возможности определить при приёме длину куска посланного send, я уже писал в комментарии. Труба (pipe) однако. Или, правильнее, поток (stream)

Если Вас интересует разбиение на куски в HTTP, то тут другая история. Смотрите раздел rfc 2616 chunked transfer coding. Ну и не следует забывать про persistent connection -- время обмена и трафик сокращает.

Comment: Человек задаёт гораздо более простой вопрос, чем про chunked encoding :) Человек боится, что если что-то не отправится сразу, то второго шанса послать уже не будет.

Comment: Ну тогда получит 0 или -1 :)